# resource file location on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I was wondering where the resource files for the reporting services is stored on the server?

My problem is that I have two SSRS serveres (a development and production server) and despite only editing in the report on the development server, using Report Builder. The changes keeps reflecting onto both serveres and it is driving me nuts...

So i was wondering if the reports a actually pushed to both serveres or its just some weird caching issue that I can't figure out, or that I have some kind of sync running in the background.

SSRS version 13.0.4604.0
Windows Server 2016

Comment: I'd use visual studio community (free version) to set the configuration for deployment for multiple environments. You can also use Azure DevOps Services for source control (free for groups of 5 or less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that the server in configured "reporting service configuration manager" was the other server